# How to properly align buttons in horizontal LinearLayout Dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-dialogfragment

I am using a simple linear layout which I am inflating in the call to `onCreateView()` in my Dialog fragment. An example of the layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Butt1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fragment_rating_horizontal_button_spacer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Butt2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/fragment_rating_horizontal_button_spacer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Butt3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the first button in this layout does not align correctly with the other two. I have determined that this is caused by having medium text size on the first button.

[image]

I would like to display a longer string in the first button by simply using smaller sized of text and keeping the 3 buttons the same.

How can I fix the alignment?

Edit. Added extra screenshot to show exaggerated problem:
[image]

Comment: use layout_weight for dividing layout into three

Comment: @Mc Gee i have edited my answer with your latest requirement that is text sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide weight and use layout_gravity for first button with small textsize

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:text="This is a very good day "
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Butt2"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Butt3"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is the simplest working solution. Thank you Ragini. I am curious as to why the layout_gravity="center" is required.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Butt1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fragment_rating_horizontal_button_spacer"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Butt2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fragment_rating_horizontal_button_spacer"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Butt3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

Its working as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="top"
              android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and for your latest requirement(i.e if you change the textsize also buttons alignment not changed) for this requirement just use

```
    android:layout_gravity="center"
```

in every button.

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Text sizes are all the same in this solution.

Comment: In all buttons textSize=20dp,so all are same.

Comment: Yes. I asked about having different text sizes.

Comment: i didn't understand what you asking? you want different textsizes for buttons?